# Get value from Bootstrap modal and return to calling function

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a js function that opens a bootstrap modal.  The bootstrap modal has date picker control.  I want to to grab the date selected and return this value to the js function that opened the bootstrap modal.  Problem is once the code executes the bootstrap modal...it continues execution within functions getDate and doStuff and does not wait for a result from bootstrap modal.

Please help.  thanks

```
function getDate() {
        var sidate;
        $("#myDateModal").modal();

        $('#dateOkBtn').click(function () {
            var datepicker = $find("<%= rdDate.ClientID %>");
            var chosenDate = datepicker.get_selectedDate().format("MM/dd/yyyy");
            sidate = chosenSIDate;

        });

        return sidate;
    }
    
    function dostuff() {
       var mydate;    
       mydate = getSelectedDate();       
     --do more stuff with mydate             
    }
    
    
<div class="modal" id="myDateModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" style="z-index: 100000" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header modal-header-primary">
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">Birth Date</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <telerik:RadDatePicker ID   ="rdDate" runat="server" ZIndex="500000">
                    <DateInput runat="server" DateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" DisplayDateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"  />
                </telerik:RadDatePicker>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="dateOkBtn" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Ok</button>
                <button id="dateCloseBtn" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Logic is flawed. You don't assign the value until user clicks on something which will happen in the future

Comment: @charlietfl I am not sure I follow.  What I want is to wait on user to select a date and then when they click on 'ok' , grab the date they selected, and return the selected date back to the dostuff() function which called the getdate function.

Comment: Buy that function only runs once when you load the page , long before the event occurs

Comment: @charlietfl so how can I get the desired behavior I am seeking?  Namely wanting the code to wait until user selects a date, in the modal, and then return that date to the function dostuff so i can perform more logic using the birth date?

Comment: Need to do everything inside the click event handler....when the value exists